# How to integrate the JIRA dashboard/ test-cycle with the automation test results(selenium + Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, jira, python-jira

I have the automation scripts written using selenium+pyhton and I want to integrate/update the test-results of my test-suite with the JIRA dashboard/ test-cycle.

Example:
I automated the test-cases which are available in JIRA dashbaord and upon running the automated test-cases(written using selenium+python) in local I want to update the test-cases in JIRA dashboard with either pass/fail more precisely based on the outcome of the test results.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using some test management system on Jira?

Comment: Plan is to go for Zephyr squad and xray is also in consideration but mostly might go for Zephyr squad